# gdal2tiles generate only missing tiles

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles

I am working on a sentinel-2 satellite images project and I need to create a map from some satellite images. The current flow is something like this:

1. Reproject the images in 3857 with gdalwarp
2. Combine the reprojected images to vrt with gdalbuildvrt
3. Generate tiles with gdal2tiles with the following options:

```
    'zoom': (MIN_ZOOM, MAX_ZOOM),
    'nb_processes': NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES,
    'srcnodata': '0,0,0',
    'resampling': 'bilinear',
    'webviewer': 'leaflet'
```

Now consider the following scenario:

1. Try to download all the images for a specific date, but for some reason only some of them get downloaded.
2. Generate the tiles using only the successfully downloaded images
3. Download the missing images after some time

The question is:
How do I integrate the newly downloaded images with the already generated tiles.
I tried using option `'resume': True` in gdal2tiles but it does not seem to work as expected and it fails to add the missing tiles to the directory tree.

An idea I got is to keep track of the images that have already been used for generating the tiles and in case new images have appeared, just run the whole process from the beginning. This way, if I have hundreds of dates, I won't need to run the whole process for all of them but just for those ones that have new images.

Any better ideas that reuse the already generated tiles?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at dedicated software like GeoWebCache or MapCache. They have built-in tools for partial re-seeding. The downside is that they cannot use GDAL VRT file directly as input. With GDAL VRT -> MapServer WMS -> MapCache you could maintain first parts of your current process.

Comment: Resume option should work `Resume mode. Generate only missing files.` Please tell more details about how it fails.

Comment: I got 5 images, I delete one of them and run gdal2tiles with resume option.
Then I add the 5th image and again run gdal2tiles with resume option and it skips everything:
"Tile generation skipped because of --resume"

As a result, the map is unchanged, wheras I expect to see the new image added to the generated pngs and loaded in leaflet..

Comment: You mean that the 5 images are your source images? Resume is checking the tiles in the output directory. If you delete some of those then gdal2tiles should re-create the tiles that are now missing. But gdal2tiles is certainly not the tool that can handle your use case when you add or replace source images.

Comment: Yes, exactly. These are the source images and I thought I could add more and generate them gradually with gdal2tiles, but I guess I was wrong. Now I get what this resume option does, thanks. As I do not expect many new images coming in the same vrt(as this happens due to failed downloads and currently I have only 1 image that has failed for one date, tested for 12 days), I decided to go with the most simple approach and generate tiles all from start only if a new image is added to the vrt file. P.S. I am organizing the source images in dates, so I build separate vrts for all dates.